# vector to string matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, vector

I am trying to convert a vector which is the following :

```
A = 
[
02376R102 ;
21871B206 ;
81765M106 ;
G3156P103]
```

into string.

It should give the following result :

```
['02376R102' ;
'21871B206' ;
'81765M106' ;
'G3156P103']
```

I can not use functions such as num2str because my vector is composed of both letters and numbers...

The ultimate goal is that I want to use the function mkdir to create directories with names in the vector A.

```
for i=1:end
mkdir('mypath', A(i))
end
```

but the mkdir functions need to have strings in A...

Thank you a lot for your help

edit :

Sorry for my mispecification, the array I am working with are CUSIP (firms code created by CRSP database) which I have uploaded with excel. The exact array when I copy paste the array is :

```
'02376R102'
'21871B206'
'81765M106'
'G3156P103'
```

Which looks like strings... But when I try the function for directories

```
i=1:end
mkdir('mypath', A(i))
end
```

matlab says that argument must contain a string.

The full code is the following :

```
CUSIP_list = unique(CUSIP)

for i = 1:length(CUSIP_list)
 mkdir('C:\Users\Marc-Aurèle\Desktop\MASTER THESIS\DATAS',CUSIP_list(i))
end
```

Comment: `A = [ 02376R102 ; ...]` is not valiud Matlab syntax. Please clarify your question

Comment: As Luis Mendo points out you can't declare an array the way you've written it. How are you inputting the names?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, I created a post below to maybe better understand my question.

Comment: shouldn't it be `mkdir('mypath', A{i})` instead?

Comment: Hi bdecaf, thanks a a lot for your answer, it works perfectly with your suggestion. May I ask the difference between {i} and [i] to indicate the index ?

Comment: The difference between {i} and [i] is that curly brackets { } are used for indexing inside cell arrays. 

A cell array may contain any kind of data in each cell. 
The main advantage is that cell array support having ANY kind of information inside a cell; EVEN ANOTHER CELL ARRAY!!

If you index a cell array with normal brackets ( ), you are getting the cell itself. When indexing with curly { }, you are getting the content inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for cells instead of strings, first I wonder how you loaded your data in, because data formats with numbers and string should be loaded in as cells, cell arrays or char arrays:

```
A = {
'02376R102' ;
'21871B206' ;
'81765M106' ;
'G3156P103'}
```

This would generate 4 x 1 cells

Alternatively you can use vertcat to concatenate them into 1 cell array

```
A = vertcat( '02376R102','21871B206')
```

which would give you 2 x 9 chars

I believe you might want to use the second method, after which you can run your function to create directories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe I did a mispecification in my question because your proposed solution does not work :( . I answered to your comment below